# GZIP seems to compress only HTML, not CSS or JavaScript

Tags: htaccess

I'm not 100% sure this is a Craft specific problem, but I'll try here, as it relates to a Craft installation.

After running a number of tests, it seems that my CSS and JavaScript files are not getting GZIP-ed. I have a `.htaccess` file in my `public` folder, and no `.htaccess` files in the subfolders below. My CSS and JS files are stored in `/assets/css`and `/assets/js` respectively (relative to the `public`folder).

My .htaccess file looks like this. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I thought the settings of the `.htacces` should work for subfolders when not overridden?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteOptions InheritDown

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but is mod_deflate installed/enabled? You also might have better luck with this one on ServerFault or Stackoverflow.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it seems to be installed, and it works for HTML. At the end of the day I think this was the drop to change away from 1&1! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use .htaccess config from [HTML Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) for better configuration. There are a lot of useful config option there.

I use this config to enable gzip compression in my personal blog, and it's worked perfectly.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>


    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-javascript" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/eot" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "image/bmp" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/vcard" \
                                      "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                      "text/xml"

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried using the boilerplate .htaccess, and it still didn't work for some reason … as I'm tiring of 1&1 I'm trying to set up a version now with Digitalocean + Serverpilot, and see if that changes things.

Answer (score 2):

Apache supports gzip with two compression modules: `mod_gzip` and `mod_deflate`. The latter is supposedly more widely available but some hosts may have one or the other.

`mod_gzip` is the older of the modules and came with Apache 1.3, `mod_deflate` is newer and compresses better, though when you're dealing with text like js/css/html, the difference is only a few bytes.

If `mod_deflate` is giving you fits, you could also try `mod_gzip` instead.

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*  
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

If Apache is running PHP as mod_php, you can also see what modules are running using something like:

```
<?php
    print_r( apache_get_modules() );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try check this. But as per the documentation, mod_deflate should be installed (and mod_gzip not), and gzip DOES work for my HTML files.